# Angular datatable view is not updating

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-datatables

I'm using angular material datatable

My datasource is simply an array .

Here's my **ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { AjouttextService } from '../ajouttext.service';
import { DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { nomchamp } from '../model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.css']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: AjouttextService) { }
  data: nomchamp[] = [{ id: "33", text: "HAHA" }, { id: "55", text: "bzlblz" }];

  displayedColumns = ['text'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
  //new UserDataSource(this.dataService);


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ajoutText(newtext: String) {
    let nouv: nomchamp = { id: "44", text: newtext };
    this.data.push(nouv);
  }
}
```

My problem is when I add new values to the data array , I don't see it on the datatable